# ViewModel using SharedPreference to store variable

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-viewmodel

I create a object to using sharedPreference.

```
private const val PREF_LOGIN_NAME = "loginName"

object LoginPreferences {

    fun getStoredName(context: Context): String {
        val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        return prefs.getString(PREF_LOGIN_NAME, "testExample")!!
    }

    fun setStoredName(context: Context, query: String) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .edit()
            .putString(PREF_LOGIN_NAME, query)
            .apply()
    }
}
```

Then I using this object with my ViewModel.

```
class LoginViewModel(private val app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    val name: String
        get() = LoginPreferences.getStoredName(app)

    fun loginSubmit() {
        LoginPreferences.setStoredName(app, name)
    }
}
```

The LoginViewModel is success binding in my LoginFragment.

But if I want to persistent save this to sharedPreference, the code I show in LoginViewModel is not work for me.

Comment: Are you checking the shared prefs immediately and the value is not there? You are using `.apply()` which means that the values will be stored asynchronously. This means that the change won't be stored immediately, to store immediately use `.commit()` although it's _more expensive_ and it's an IO operation so I suggest moving to background thread if you need to use that.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in the `prefs.getString(...)` method represents a *default* value, not the value itself.

`prefs.getString(PREF_LOGIN_NAME, "testExample")` means that if your shared preferences could not find the value associated with the specified key (`PREF_LOGIN_NAME`), it will return the default value instead - which is `"testExample"`

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

If you want to clear your shared preferences, you can do:

```
prefs.edit().clear().apply()
```

Then, if you call `getStoredName(...)` for the first time, you will get `testExample` as a result (assuming you don't call `setStoredName(...)` before this).

Comment: If I binding `LoginSubmit` to my LoginFragment, it seems not success persistent save the name variable for me, could explain why it is happened?

Comment: @ccd Are you clearing your shared preferences anywhere? If you want `name` to persist, then you should not clear your shared pref unless the user logs out.